# How to use an IAM certificate in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2, hosting a simple http server.
I want to make use of the HTTPS so to have my traffic hidden, but I made the mistake of buying a domain via AWS and to generate a certificate for it via AWS.

Mistake because it seems I cannot simply import that certificate in my EC2 (maybe because, if AWS gave me that cert as file, I could use it in any number of application of mine).
So, what I have to do in order to use it?

Move my web application to an elastic load balancer? Use a cointainer to host it?
What is the less expensive?

Comment: If you created the certificate with AWS Certificate Manager service (you do not specify) You can export the cert with AWS REST API in any flavor of SDK you like: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/APIReference/API_ExportCertificate.html

Comment: Yes I did with certificate manage